# How to display order total weight in “Order & Account Information” section in Magento 2?

Tags: php, xml, frontend, magento2, magento2.1

I want to display total weight of an order in "Order & Account Information" section in Magento 2.1.9

When I clicked on an order from order grid, I go to order info page and I get all the info about the order except the total weight.

I want to display ordered items total weight under the "Placed from IP" info. For example: Order Total Weight: 520.15 lbs

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same in my Mag1 site and I couldn't find many Mag2 answers for this feature.

I was able to find some code that was close and managed to get it to work. I've added it under the order status section of the info.phtml file. The file is under vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view

```
<tr>
    <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Weight')) ?></th>
    <td><span id="order_status"><?= $block->escapeHtml($order->getWeight()) ?>
    </span></td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps.